# baseurl isn't doing anything in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to avoid long imports:

```
import x from '../../../../../../../lib/tool"
```

I want to import it as

```
import x from 'lib/tool"
```

so inside my tsconfig.json file, here's my config:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node16",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "declarationDir": "./@types",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": ["./@types", "node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

and here's the folder structure:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── index.js
│   └── tools
│       └── test.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── tools
│       └── test.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── @types
    ├── index.d.ts
    ├── index.d.ts.map
    └── tools
        ├── test.d.ts
        └── test.d.ts.map
```

I am getting this output when I run

```
npx tsc -w
```

```
[11:36:32 AM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[11:36:32 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

and I am getting this output when I run:

```
node ./dist/index.js
```

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/xam/Desktop/test/src/dist/index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.15.0
```

and here's the compiled ./dist/index.js file code:

```
import { testMe } from "tools/test";
testMe();
```

Comment: I believe that both `baseUrl` and `include` should simply be `"src"` and `["src"]` respectively (e.g. `"include": ["src"]`) and not `"./src"` (which is a relative path)

Comment: You need to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths, by design ts does not change paths